# Log for a powershell script

Tags: powershell, logging, installation

I have a powershell script which has the following contents:-

```
$Dir = "Drive:\"
$Exe = "Any.exe"
$Args = '/quiet /norestart'
Start-Process "$Directory\$Exe" $Args -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

This does not make any log.

I want to have a log of all the tasks being done by this powershell script, that is why i tried this:-

```
$Args = '/quiet /norestart /L*V C:\Log.txt'
```

and i have created this file ( Log.txt ) in my C  drive explicitly.

But, this doesn't work.
If anyone knows how to do it, please help.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: That looks like the accepted logging arguments for `msiexec`. That's not going to apply to an arbitrary `Any.exe`. What, exactly, do you want logged?

Comment: The tasks/operations being performed by this powershell script.

Comment: Your powershell script *isn't performing any interesting actions*. It's running a single EXE, which then does stuff.

Comment: It may be that the desire is to capture standard output/error from the executable in a file, but that isn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you Any.exe use this file for log, it isn't?

May by try to add quote to your path log like it:

```
$Args = '/quiet /norestart /L*V "C:\Log.txt"'
```

Otherwise check if you have permission to write to c:\ (try to write in c:\temp\Log.txt by example)

Answer (score 0):

It worked using $Args = '/quiet /norestart /log C:\log.txt'